# The required antiforgery cookie ".AspNetCore.Antiforgery.JREqX-HygdI" is not present

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core-webapi, csrf

backend Im using aspnetcore webapi, after sending the login credentials from frontend and after authenticaion in backend I'm adding the csrf token in cookie and then fetch in frontend and add in other request as header , but it is not able to validate , it keep checking the .AspNetCore.Antiforgery.JREqX-HygdI, not the one that I pass in header

```
public class CsrfValidationMiddleware
    {
        private readonly IAntiforgery _antiforgery;
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

        public CsrfValidationMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, IAntiforgery antiforgery)
        {
            _next = next ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(next));
            _antiforgery = antiforgery ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(antiforgery));
        }

        public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
        {
            var isGetRequest = string.Equals("GET", context.Request.Method, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

            if (context.Request.Path == "/v1/api/login")
            {
                // Obtain and store anti-forgery tokens, including setting the cookie
                var antiforgeryTokens = _antiforgery.GetAndStoreTokens(context);

                // Access the CSRF token
                var csrfToken = antiforgeryTokens.RequestToken;

                // Add CSRF token to response headers
                context.Response.Cookies.Append("XSRF-TOKEN", csrfToken, new CookieOptions
                {
                    HttpOnly = false,
                    SameSite = SameSiteMode.None, // Adjust based on your requirements
                    Secure = true // If your site is served over HTTPS
                });
            }

            // Validate anti-forgery token for non-GET requests
            if (!isGetRequest && context.Request.Path != "/v1/api/login")
            {
                await _antiforgery.ValidateRequestAsync(context);
            }

            // Call the next middleware in the pipeline
            await _next(context);
        }
    }
```

React typescript calling api

```
 static api() {
    const jwtToken = localStorage.getItem('token')
    let token = Cookies.get("XSRF-TOKEN");
    console.log('maq',token)

    return axios.create({
      baseURL: process.env.BaseASE_URL, 
      headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + jwtToken,
        'X-XSRF-TOKEN':localStorage.getItem('csrf')
      }
    })
  }
```

tried this blog
https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/csrf-tokens-angularjsjquery-asp-net-core/

Answer (score 0):

I checked the blog you shared and I found that the blog is trying to add AntiForgery key into Angular SPA + web api backend. And it is not recommended because a JWT might be a good option. Here's [what I found](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/27901#issuecomment-728849254) when I test in my side.

Following the official document for asp.net core, we could know that Anti-forgery key is used for preventing Cross-Site request, if we are trying to send the request from another client app then it is cross site, which should be avoided.

Per my test, if you want to solve your exception `The required antiforgery cookie ".AspNetCore.Antiforgery.JREqX-HygdI" is not present`, you can easily add the option `options.Cookie.Name = "XSRF-TOKEN";` in `builder.Services.AddAntiforgery`. This will make the validation mechanism to refer to cookie name which is you set in the request response. But this would bring another exception `Validation of the provided antiforgery token failed. The cookie token and the request token were swapped` and we can't change the app to only validate the request header but ignore the cookie. In the [sample code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-8.0#javascript) shared in the official document, I found that no matter I stop adding the request header or deleting the cookie, I will fail to call the API.

worked with request header + cookie

[image]

not working without cookie

[image]

not working without request header

[image]

=====================================

You are now putting the antiforgery Tokens inside the request header, but the error `The required antiforgery cookie ".AspNetCore.Antiforgery.JREqX-HygdI"` is indicating that your api is trying to find it in cookie, so we need to change this behavior in web api.

We have [a document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-8.0#javascript) here where guide us to change the behavior:

> Assuming the script sends the token in a request header called
> X-XSRF-TOKEN, configure the antiforgery service to look for the
> X-XSRF-TOKEN header:

```
builder.Services.AddAntiforgery(options => options.HeaderName = "X-XSRF-TOKEN");
```

Comment: this what I have configured
'builder.Services.AddAntiforgery(options =>
{
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = false;
    options.HeaderName = "X-XSRF-TOKEN"; // Customize the header name if needed
    options.SuppressXFrameOptionsHeader = false;
    options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None; // Adjust based on your requirements
    options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always; // If your site is served over HTTPS

});'

Comment: 'builder.Services.AddAntiforgery(options =>
{
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = false;
    options.HeaderName = "X-XSRF-TOKEN"; // Customize the header name if needed
    options.SuppressXFrameOptionsHeader = false;
    options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None; // Adjust based on your requirements
    options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always; // If your site is served over HTTPS

});'

Comment: I updated my post after testing in my side for a whole day.. Impossible and is not recommending to using Anti-forgery in SPA + web api. Unless we could set the AspNetCore.Antiforgery.xxx cookie be sent along with the API request.

Comment: in addition, as you can see in the blog about the part to set cookie, you could see `context.Response.Cookies.Append("XSRF-TOKEN", token,new CookieOptions { HttpOnly = false });` which doesn't set cookie option for `SameSite = SameSiteMode.None` so that the cookie isn't set for the Anuglar SPA